# C. Нарушение прав доступа при чтении. Шифр Цезаря

Tags: c, строки, файлы

Извините, если я делаю что-то не так или туплю (Пишу на С буквально второй день).

**ЗАДАНИЕ само:**

Шифр Цезаря. Считываем с input.txt и записываем обработанный текст в output.txt. Последняя строка input - СДВИГ в алфавите.

**ПРОБЛЕМА:**
В ""strcat(res_new, new);"" строке ошибка : "нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу...".  Не понимаю(не бейте палками, пожалуйста), почему там ошибка, если точно такая же строка strcat(res, buf); не вызывает ошибку. (комментарии к кускам кода присутствуют)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//понятно, что за функции
int isdigit(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')return 1;
    return 0;
}
int isalpha(char c)
{
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //для сохранения одной строки
    char buf[100];
    //для сохранения всего input
    char res[1000]="";
    //для сохранения обработанного текста
    char res_new[1000] ="";
    //сдвиг в алфавите
    int shift = 0;

    FILE* input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    FILE* output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    
    // Тут я считываю весь файл по строкам и сохраняю (с помощью конкатенации) в res. Надеюсь, уже тут не облажался
    if (input != NULL) {
        while (fgets(buf, 99, input))
        {
            strcat(res, buf);
        }
        //fputs(res, output);


        fclose(input);
    }
    // тут я ищу последнюю строку, чтобы вытащить из текста ЦИФРЫ из узнать сдвиг
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = strlen(res) - 1; res[i] != '\n'; i--, k++)
    {
        int digit = (int)res[i] - '0';

        shift += digit * pow(10, k);

    }

    // собственно сама замена и сохранение в res_new
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(res); i++)
    {

        char new = res[i];
        //если это БУКВА, то сдвигаем
        if (isalpha(res[i]))
        {
            if (new >= 'a' && new <= 'z')
            {
                new = new + shift;
                while (new > 'z')
                {
                    new -= 26;
                }
            }
            else if (new >= 'A' && new <= 'Z')
            {
                new += shift;
                while (new > 'Z')
                {
                    new -= 26;
                }
            }
        }

        // Наш current символ впихиваем в res_new
        strcat(res_new, new);

        //Типа проверка на то, надо ли дальше идти, или там уже ПОСЛЕДНЯЯ строка с цифрами
        if (res[i + 1] == '\n' && isdigit(res[i + 2]))
        {
            break;
        }
    }


    // просто принт, до сюда я не доходил, ибо не работает
    printf("%s", res_new);
    fclose(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strcat не умеет добавлять один символ. Он думает, что второй параметр char* и будет читать какой то мусор. поэтому и падает. Что делать? просто вручную добавить символ. Я напишу многословно, но Вы попробуйте оптимизировать

```
int len = strlen(res_new);
res_new[len] = new;
res_new[len+1] = '\0';
```

если длину хранить где то в другом месте, то можно сильно сократить до одной строки.

Comment: `{ char news [ 2 ] = { new , '\00' } ; strcat ( res_new , news ) ; }`